# Check if offline application cache disabled by browser

Tags: html, firefox, offline, browser-history, application-cache

So I've got an application that stores offline data using an ApplicationCache.  Long story short, it's silently dying for users who don't have offline data enabled, most commonly because they've got history turned off or are using private browsing, and I'd like to catch this and give the user a clear error.

It *appears* that this can be detected by checking the cache's state, which will return 0 `UNCACHED` when there is no cache... but I'm not sure if that means that there is no cache *yet*, or that there's no cache *guaranteed* (and because there should be, something's wrong).  The [official definition](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#application-cache-api) is less than useful:

```
UNCACHED (numeric value 0)
The ApplicationCache object's cache host is not associated with an application
cache at this time.
```

In practice, though, aborting on `cache.status==0` seems to work fine at least on Firefox.  Am I doing it right, or is there a better way?  Extra points if somebody can dig up a state diagram.

**Update**: Nope, it also returns 0/UNCACHED if the user has never been to that page before.  Gar!

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `error` event on `applicationCache`. When this fires and `applicationCache.status===applicationCache.UNCACHED`, one reason among *many* is that caching is disabled. The message to the user may *suggest* that caching is turned off.

Comment: Hi, could this also indicate that applicationCache isn't supported on the device / browser in question? or would the window.applicationCache property just not exist at all in this case?