# Fallback of application cache is not shown

Tags: html, application-cache

I have a web-app which uses the application cache feature for local storage.
I would like to show the user a certain html file if he is not online. For this purpose the FALLBACK part in the manifest is used so far I have understood.

For simplicity I have at the moment only one file to cache in the manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
someFile.css

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/ offline.html
```

I first load the page with internet access so the browser can download someFile.css and offline.html and store it locally.
Then I interrupt the internet access to the server and reload the page. Now I expect to see offline.html in the browser, but this is not the case.

Chrome indeed tries to load the files which are needed by index.html (the master) but are not stated in the manifest. Checking the Network tab in the debug window shows the following line for these files:

```
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

From what cache are these files taken? The browser cache is disabled when the debug window is shown and the application cache does not have these files.

When I then check the Preview in the Network tab, it shows the offline.html for each of these files. Now it seems that the offline.html is loaded as desired but Chrome expects something else (the stated JS- and CSS files in the index.html) and therefore misinterprets the received offline.html:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://domain/someFile.css".
```

What can I do to see offline.html?
I simply would like to see offline.html when the server can't be reached.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if offline application cache disabled by browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281382/check-if-offline-application-cache-disabled-by-browser)